# Python - Filter dataframe based on the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, combinations

I am performing data analysis on stocks, analyzing approx. 600,000 lines running various criteria. So far, there are maximum number of combinations it has satisfied is 20. I found a way to generate all combinations. Now next thing is to run the filter these combinations and provide the result on how many of the scenario is generating profit. The code i have is taking way longer time and so suggesting if there is anything else i can use. Below is the code

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools


# Input Entries
dataFile = "ReferenceFile.txt" # Enter the data file with all analysis

combinationFile = "Combination.csv" # Enter the combination file, the file should be in csv file

ResultFile = "Result.csv" # Enter the result file, the file should be in csv file


#Import files
dfData = pd.read_csv(dataFile, sep = ",")

dfData.fillna("", inplace=True)

dfData["AAA"] ="AAA" # adding this column to run different set of combinations at once, combatination can be 2, 3,....10,...20 fields


i = 0
file = open(combinationFile, "r") # opening the file
file
for line in file:
    dfTemp = dfData
    line = line.replace(("\n"),"") 
    line = line.split(',')
    dfTempData = pd.DataFrame(line)
    b = ""
    for col_name in dfTempData[0]:
        z = b + "|"+ col_name
        
        
        if col_name == "AAA":
            A1=1
        else:
            dfTemp=dfTemp[dfData[col_name].str.contains(col_name)]
        
            dfTempP=dfTemp[dfData[col_name].str.contains("Profit")]
        
            a = dfTempP.shape[0]/dfTemp.shape[0]
        
            b = z
                
    #c = str(b) + "," + str(dfTemp.shape[0]) + str(dfTempP.shape[0])  
    
    
    txtfile = open(ResultFile, "a")
    txtfile.write(str(dfTemp.shape[0]) + str("|") + str(dfTempP.shape[0]) + "|" + str(b) + "\n")
    #txtfile.close()
                
    
    i = i + 1
    

txtfile = open(ResultFile, "a")
txtfile.close()
print("Complete")
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

[ReferenceFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTTnD.jpg)
ReferenceFile is a text file separated by comma. The 2nd section of the image shows data in excel file

combinationFile
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97b2S.jpg)

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA, Price is lower than 4DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA positive, Price crosses 4DAY EMA negative

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA, Price is lower than 4DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA positive, Price crosses 4DAY EMA negative

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA, Price is lower than 4DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA positive,AAA

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA, Price is lower than 4DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA negative,AAA

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA positive, Price crosses 4DAY EMA negative,AAA
Price is lower than 4DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA positive,AAA,AAA

Price is lower than 4DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA negative,AAA,AAA

Price crosses 4DAY EMA positive, Price crosses 4DAY EMA negative,AAA,AAA

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA, Price is lower than 4DAY EMA,AAA,AAA

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA positive,AAA,AAA

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA, Price crosses 4DAY EMA negative,AAA,AAA

Price greater than 4 DAY EMA,AAA,AAA,AAA

Price is lower than 4DAY EMA,AAA,AAA,AAA

Price crosses 4DAY EMA positive,AAA,AAA,AAA

Price crosses 4DAY EMA negative,AAA,AAA,AAA

Comment: Hello Ed! In cases like this of your question you can provide images of your sample dataset (even let's say the first 20). Else some people might not like it and down voting your question causing you not to ask questions in the future. Thank you!

Comment: @StakeOffended .... Thank you for the advice..... i have added the image of sample data for both files

Comment: @Chris... new to stack overflow..... i have added the image of the dataset